# Can i change an argument separator? discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I created a command with multiple arguments, but they are all separated with space, and if any arg contain space, it just broke, so my question is, how can i change it to a '.' character for example?

Tried to do something like that, its partially working but still breaks the whole program.

`const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +./);`

Comment: `.split('.')` should work

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down what each part and function of your code does.

`message.content` is the content of your message. For example, "!ban @user spamming"

`.slice(prefix.length)`, when used from a string, returns everything after the first parameter of the function. If there's a second parameter, which isn't used here, that is the end index of what's returning.
**It's important to note that the index starts from 0, but `prefix.length` starts from 1.** Since there's usually a character after your command, `prefix.length + 1` is not needed.
For example, `@user spamming`.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Now, you need to convert this into an array. For now, let's use a space. `.split(' ')` should work. Whenever it sees that character (or regex) in that array, it will split it as an array. For example, `['@user', 'spamming']`.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

To have `.` as the separator instead of a whitespace, simply change `.split(' ')` to `.split('.')`.

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split('.');
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a code similar to the one you posted, that is:

```
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
```

Maybe, with the `.trim()`, your code will start working also with spaces.

By the way, as suggested by @Zsolt Meszaros, your code becomes:

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split('.');
```